# Variable list of arguments in a LESS mixin

Tags: css, less

I need to declare a LESS mixin with a variable number of arguments, and pass it to the mixin, like this:

```
.linear-gradient(@color1, @color2) {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@color1, @color2); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@color1, @color2); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(@color1, @color2);
    background: linear-gradient(@color1, @color2); 
}

.linear-gradient(@color1, @color2, @color3) { ...
.linear-gradient(@color1, @color2, @color3, @color4) { ...

... // usage with a variable number of arguments: 
body > header {
    .linear-gradient(red, yellow, blue);
```

As described [in the documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) I can use `@arguments` and `@rest` keywords, but is not very clear for me how exactly should it be used in my case...

**Here is [my PEN for testing](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BodGBE?editors=110)**

Comment: @Harry: the OP of "duplicate" does not deal with `@arguments` I ask about

Comment: Please check the answer posted by **esp**. The problem might be different but the solution is the same (you can see it in the answer posted here by Amit also).

Comment: @Harry: it may fit, however **esp** didn't mentioned the `;`detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@rest` is not a keyword, its a sample identifier use to demonstate `...`. It could have any other name.

To fix your code:

```
.linear-gradient(@rest...) {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@rest); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@rest); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(@rest);
    background: linear-gradient(@rest); 
}

body > header {
    .linear-gradient(red, yellow, blue);
}
```

You could replace `@rest` with `@arguments` inside the mixin as you use the entire input as a "variable arguments list". Then you could also omit the `@rest` identifier altogether:

```
.linear-gradient(...) {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@arguments); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@arguments); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(@arguments);
    background: linear-gradient(@arguments); 
}
```

There's no difference between the 2 versions.

But all of that is not what you want at all. The 2 solutions above will result in a CSS that looks like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(red yellow blue);
```

That is because the values are interpreted as individual arguments, and are concatenated in a string with spaces.

What you need is this:

```
.linear-gradient(@colors) {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@colors); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@colors); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(@colors);
    background: linear-gradient(@colors); 
}

body > header {
    .linear-gradient(red, yellow, blue;);
}
```

This tells *LESS* that the argument passed into the mixin is a single variable, with comma's inside. That translates to your required output.

Comment: tried but does not work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BodGBE?editors=110

Comment: @Serge (and Amit): When the values have a `,` in between them, you need to end it with a `;` for it to work. So, the call should be `.linear-gradient(red, yellow, blue;);` or `.linear-gradient(red, yellow;);`.

Comment: @Harry - yes, was editing as you commented :-)

Comment: @Amit: you have a little error in "gradientA" ;)

Comment: @Serge - corrected. I don't know where that came from :-)

Comment: also, perhaps you should fix your first sample code with ";"?

Comment: @Serge these were intentionally left as is, but I did add a section explaining the difference.